# Unable to test restangular service using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test the below restangular service call using `jasmine-karma`:

```
appServices.service('categoryListService', function (Restangular, utilityService) {

    /**
     * @param {objecet} deffered
     * @returns {undefined}
     * @functionality: call service to get category list.
     */
    this.getCategoryList = function(deffered) {
        utilityService.setLoading(true, 'Loading Categories');

        Restangular.one('someService.do').get().then(function(response) {
            utilityService.setLoading(false, '');
            deffered.resolve(response.plain());
        },
        function(response) {
            utilityService.setLoading(false, '');
            alert('Error Code: ' + response.status + '<br/>' + 'Error Status: ' + response.statusText);
            console.log(response);
        });        
    };
});
```

Can anyone provide the jasmine approach to test the same?